# I am trying to sync my project in android studio this is what is telling me

Tags: android, gradle, groove

Cannot convert relative path offline\daemon\7.0.2 to an absolute file.
I need help please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please give enough details to reproduce this problem